# discord.js client.guilds.cache returns empty collection

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Title basically says everything, when i do client.guilds.cache() it returns an empty collection. No idea what to do

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(g=>{g.id=="876857023256465468"})
    console.log(client.guilds.cache)
```

Comment: I assume that `console.log(client.guilds.cache)` is inside some event's callback, like `ready`, right? If no that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the intents, try using `32767` bitfield flag, 32767 stands for `Intents.ALL` therefore would provide all the intents that are available to the client